# Can't pass full string to delegate

Tags: vb.net

I have a backgroundworker to work on objects and queries, but it calls a delegate to write in a datagridview, but when I add 1 character to the string for the delegate, it no longer writes to the grid and enters the me.invokerequired, if I remove this character it goes to the else.
From here I call the delegate

```
If jsonElemento.cantidad_errores <> 0 Then
  If jsonErrores.Count = 0 Then
    vector = fila("docentry").ToString + ";" + fila("tipo") + ";" + " " + "i add the char here (;)" + jsonElemento.cantidad_errores.ToString
    gridError(vector)
  Else
    vector = fila("docentry").ToString + ";" + fila("tipo") + ";" + jsonErrores(0).mensaje_error.ToString + ";" + jsonElemento.cantidad_errores.ToString
    gridError(vector)
  End If
End If
```

And this is my delegate

```
Public Sub gridError(argumentos As String)
    If Me.InvokeRequired() Then
        Me.Invoke(New Action(Of String)(AddressOf gridError), argumentos)
    Else
        vector = argumentos.Split(delimitadores, StringSplitOptions.None)
        If vector.Count = 3 Then
            DataErrores.Rows.Add(vector(0), vector(1), vector(2))
        ElseIf vector.Count = 2 Then
            DataErrores.Rows.Add(vector(0), " ", vector(1))
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

I cant understand why 1 character make this difference and i have the same issue with the if vector.count = 3

Comment: That is not a good theory.  Ensure that the Load event has fired before starting the worker so you can be sure that the form initialized itself.  And don't use InvokeRequired when you *know* it must be true, other than to throw an exception to indicate something is wrong with the form.

Comment: I've always set `WorkerReportsProgress = true` and used the `ReportProgress` method on the bgw to update UI elements; it fires the `ProgressChanged` event on the UI thread that created the worker (which should be the same thread that created your grid) so no invoking required. You can pass an object state in ReportProgress